# BlackBerry Data Usage

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, networking, network-monitoring

Using the RIM APIs. is there an accurate way of collecting the amount of data coming in and out of a service provider (Not including WiFi/Bluetooth data).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have tried RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived() and RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent() and they also include Wi-Fi usage, at least when routing through BlackBerry Infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent()` and `RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived()` to monitor data usage?